# Numerical approximation of stochastic partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, simulation

**Background**
I want to approximate an SPDE of adensity process $V_t$. The Brownian motion part is given (up to a certain precision level $\epsilon>0$) by a brownian trajectory $t\mapsto w_t$. The starting point being $V_0(x)=\delta_{x_0}(x)$ (i.e. $V_0(x)=1$ if $x=x_0$) and $V^{(n)}=u_{n\epsilon}$, (considering that we have a Brownian path) I'm given the following deterministic PDE

$$
du_t(x)=-\mu(t,x,L^{(n-1)})\partial_x u_t(x)dt + \frac{1}{2}\sigma(t,x)\rho(t,L^{(n-1)})\partial_{xx}u_t(x)dt\\
-\sigma(t,x)\sqrt{1-\rho(t,L^{(n-1)})^2}\partial_x u_t(x)dw_t,
$$
and $L^{(n)}=1-\int_0^\infty V^{(n)}(x)dx, for $x>0$.

**Problem**
I'm in need of an approach to simulate this in *R*. I already looked up the package *Sim.DiffProc* and also others like *simecol* or the general packages for solving PDEs and ODEs didn't really help me (I don't have that much experience in simulating this).

**Question**
I kindly ask you to either provide me with information on how to approach solving the (determinisitc) PDE in *R* or with some advice on which package I could use (considering that the parameters $\sigma, \mu, \rho$ are dependent on $L^{(n-1)}$.

Thank you in advance.

**P.S.** Although I know that this might belong to other communities, I'm specifically interested in the numerical solution/mathematical approach of this thing so I supposed it was right on MSE.